# On Safari 14.0.2, MediaRecorder dataavailable handler captures empty blob

Tags: javascript, safari, web-mediarecorder

I was using MediaRecorder API to record a webcam session from Safari (v14.0.2). The `handleDataAvailable` will collect the streaming data every 500ms and push the blob into the `recordedBlobs` array.

```
this.recordedBlobs = []
this.mediaRecorder = new window.MediaRecorder(this.stream, {mimeType: "video/mp4;codecs=avc1"})
this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', this.handleStop)
this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('error', this.handleError)
this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener(
  'dataavailable',
  this.handleDataAvailable
)
this.mediaRecorder.start(500) // Collect blob data every 500ms

handleDataAvailable = (event) => {
  this.recordedBlobs.push(event.data)
}
```

But what I observed from the console log is that some blobs will have a size 0 and type to "". The empty blob happens randomly; sometimes there is none, sometimes there are many inside the array.

It creates an even bigger problem  when I concatenate all blobs to create a whole new blob, the new blob is corrupted. In the following case, the 2nd blob has size 0, each blob duration is 500ms, the video should have a duration of 5 seconds, but I can only play the first 500ms.

The issue only happens on Safari, Chrome works fine. Any pointers will be really appreciated!

```
Array (11)
0 Blob {size: 402074, type: "video/mp4", slice: function, text: function, arrayBuffer: function}
1 Blob {size: 0, type: "", slice: function, text: function, arrayBuffer: function}
2 Blob {size: 726104, type: "video/mp4", slice: function, text: function, arrayBuffer: function}
3 Blob {size: 355672, type: "video/mp4", slice: function, text: function, arrayBuffer: function}
4 Blob {size: 374119, type: "video/mp4", slice: function, text: function, arrayBuffer: function}
5 Blob {size: 369714, type: "video/mp4", slice: function, text: function, arrayBuffer: function}
6 Blob {size: 378604, type: "video/mp4", slice: function, text: function, arrayBuffer: function}
7 Blob {size: 381219, type: "video/mp4", slice: function, text: function, arrayBuffer: function}
8 Blob {size: 434928, type: "video/mp4", slice: function, text: function, arrayBuffer: function}
9 Blob {size: 359651, type: "video/mp4", slice: function, text: function, arrayBuffer: function}
10 Blob {size: 217731, type: "video/mp4", slice: function, text: function, arrayBuffer: function}
```

Comment: The empty Blob in the middle shouldn't be an issue for the final Blob, can you show how you concatenate this?

Comment: I just call `new window.Blob(this.recordedBlobs, {type: "video/mp4;codecs=avc1"})`. I think the blob shouldn't be empty because `dataavailable ` will be triggered every 500ms and a new blob will be created. If the size is 0, it means it recorded nothing. Am I right?

Comment: No, it just means they didn't think enough information went into the stream to be worth its own chunk. If you look at your screenshot, the third chunk is about twice bigger than other ones -> the data that you expected to come in the second chunk went into the third. And for your error, how do you determine the video is corrupted? Your mime type is incorrect to generate the Blob, so if you try to read that Blob from a <video>, it won't work, it should be `new Blob(this.recordedBlobs, {type: "video/mp4"})`. ANd FWIW, it works fine on my Safari.

Comment: I changed the type to `video/mp4`, but still, when I tried to replay the video from `window.URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob)`, it always stopped at the timestamp where blob has a size of 0 :(

Comment: Try to filter it out (`new Blob(this.recordedBlobs.filter(chunk=>chunk.size))`), but once again, here (Safari 14.1) it works.

Comment: I actually tried that too, remove all empty blob if there is any, but still the same issue. Mine is 14.0.2, I need to upgrade my macOS to verify.

Comment: Yes, as I said, empty Blobs in the middle shouldn't have any incidence. That Safari had a bug in their previous version is possible though, but it's probably not linked to these empty Blobs, which are quite normal.

Comment: @Kaiido FWIW, if all blobs are non-empty, issue will not happen. It only happens when there is at least one empty blob in the array.

Comment: @Kaiido is it possible to force handleDataAvailable to give non-empty blobs?

Comment: You can try to let the browser handle itself the size of the chunks, by not passing anything to `start()`.

Comment: Ahh, that's a good workaround; I may give it a try. But is there any side effect from a single giant blob compared to several fragmented small blobs?

Comment: Smaller chunks might result in a bigger final file (because the browser will probably try to generate more keyframes than necessary). Then there are many browser bugs, some I don't know of, like this Safari 14.0.2 one, some I do know of, like Chrome which will forget to send to the final Blob audio data from a stream where video has been muted after the recording started, but that shouldn't be your case, so for you, not passing a default chunk's duration should be better in all aspects.

Comment: Just tried, and still not working. It seems I hit this bug: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues/1281

Comment: The only hope right now is to fix the empty blob chunk issue

Comment: Can you listen to the mute events on all the tracks of your mediastream? Does it fire? If so you should be able to at least handle the bug happening, and even start a new MediaRecorder in the unmute event (if any). But once again, everything works fine for me in Safari 14.1

Comment: No, there is no mute & unmute event :( Really appreciate all your inputs here @Kaiido 

Comment: Just an update, I tried 14.1.2, no issue! So I think it's some legacy bug in the old version.